# dd stderr output CR ( ^M / 0xD ) at the end of the lines

Tags: vim, newline, dd

I try to log dd's output to a file. For example:

> dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null status=progress 2> output.log

Then when I try to open output.log with a vim, I see one long line and ^M sign where newline should be.

```
2086523392 bytes (2,1 GB, 1,9 GiB) copied, 5 s, 417 MB/s^M2497234432 bytes (2,5 GB, 2,3 GiB) copied, 6 s, 416 MB/s^M
```

I can properly view output.log in vim only doing search&replace `:%s/\%x0D/\r/g`, or this `:e ++ff=mac`

It seems that dd uses mac's CR symbol in output for line break, instead of unix's LF. Why?

Comment: Well, I'm on a Mac and I get Line Feeds. Maybe we can swap our machines?

Answer (score 0):

CR stands for "carriage return". That implies moving a carriage of your "typewriter" all the way to the left *without* scrolling "a sheet of paper". In other words, it works as "home" key when program outputs text on terminal. So every new "progress output" erases the previous one. Of course, it only works like that in terminal, not when redirected to file. Quite probably, you are not supposed to have `status=progress` and redirection at the same time.